# cv2 VideoWriter outputs empty 0 second video

Tags: python, opencv

I have been using the code

```
video_name = 'minions.avi'
video = cv2.VideoWriter(video_name, cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'DIVX'),  0, 1, (1280, 580))
```

to save videos made with cv2 , however the output videos are 0 second empty videos. Does anyone know why?

Comment: that piece of codes only initialize a video writer object. Did you write any frames with `video.write(frame)` after that?

Comment: @QuangHoang Yes I have been adding frames via `video.write(frame)` I confirmed this by doing `cv2.imshow(frame)`